# Is it possible to create custom shaped GeoFence?

Tags: uwp, geofencing

I want to create a GeoFence around a location but with a shape other than a circle.  Is it possible to define a custom shape to a GeoFence, by using a series of geographic points?

Answer (score 1):

From the [UWP documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation.geofencing.geofence) for the `Geofence(String id, IGeoshape geoshape)` constructor:

> The *geoshape* parameter must be a non-null Geocircle with a SpatialReferenceId that matches the platform or an exception will be thrown.

It seems that no other geoshape than a circle is currently allowed.